# What is the dimension of the range of T if T is one to one? Explain

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Full Question:

Let T: R^n -> R^m be a linear transformation.

A). What is the dimension of the range of T if T is one-to-one? Explain.

Ans(a): Range is a subspace of R^m, and since T is one to one then the dim of NS(T)=o, and since a pivot exists in every col then a pivot exists in every row because of T being 1-1. Therefore the dim(range(t))= R^m, but i am not completely sure.

B). What is the dimension of the kernel of T if T maps R^n onto R^m? explain.

Ans(b): I would say the dimension of the kernel of T would be R^m, but i am unsure as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimension formula: $\dim(ker(T))+\dim(Im(T))=\dim(\Bbb R^n)=n$. If $T$ is one-to-one, then $\dim(Im(T))=n$ which can only happen if $m\geq n$. If $T$ is onto, then $\dim(ker(T))=n-m$, so $n-m\geq 0$ so $n\geq m$.

Comment: if im understanding your answer correctly i think what i had was right lol? sorry still a bit confused

Comment: Firstly, you cannot say $\dim(range(T))=\Bbb R^m$ rather you say $\dim(range(T))=m$, as $\Bbb R^m$ is a vector space, not a natural number (same for kernel). More importantly, in (a) I don't believe you can assert that there will be a pivot in each row and column (assuming I know what you mean by pivot), as that would assert that $T$ has full rank (which may not be true). Also, $\dim(ker(T))\neq m$ unless $n=2m$. I think my answer may be cleaner, and uses a fundamental equation that is very useful for these types of problems.

Comment: ah ok thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. Also, in part (a): you were on the right track by saying $\dim NS(T)=0$, assuming $NS$ means null space, but from there I would use the dimension formula (i.e. the rank-nullity theorem) to show $\dim (range(T))=m$ whenever $m\geq n$.